# How to propagate and customise events to other classes?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, serial-port

I have a SerialPortWrapper class that deals with the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`, which includes the `OnSerialDataRecevied` event handler. The following is an outline of the class, and it works:

```
public class SerialPortWrapper : ISerialPortWrapper
{
    public event SerialDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceviedHandler;    

    private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

    public SerialPortWrapper()
    {
        this._serialPort = new SerialPort
        {
            // configure SerialPort
        };

        this._serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceviedHandler;
        this._serialPort.DataReceived += OnSerialDataRecevied;
    }

    public void Write(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count)
    {
        this._serialPort.Write(bytes, offset, count);
    }

    public void OnSerialDataRecevied(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        var bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sp.ReadExisting());
    }
}
```

I also have a class that uses the SerialPortWrapper. I would like an event to fire in this class when `OnSerialDataRecevied` fires. Preferably, this event object would contain custom data that a `SecurityPanel` would be concerned with, rather than `SerialPort` data

You can see in the code below that I tried to add `SecurityDataRecevied` as a handler for the SerialPortWrapper's `DataReceviedHandler` but that doesn't work.

```
public class SecurityPanel : ISecurityPanel
{
    private readonly ISerialPortWrapper _serialPortWrapper;

    public SecurityPanel(ISerialPortWrapper serialPortWrapper)
    {
        _serialPortWrapper = serialPortWrapper;

        _serialPortWrapper.DataReceviedHandler += SecurityDataRecevied;
    }

    private void SecurityDataRecevied(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this doens't fire. Prefereably it would have a custom EventArgs object, 
        // rather than SerialDataReceivedEventArgs 
    }

    public byte SendMessage(Message message)
    {
        // get bytes from message and send them to the SerialPort
        _serialPortWrapper.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);            
    }
}
```

The questions I have are

- How can I propagate the event to classes that are using the SerialPortWrapper?
- How can I make these custom events that are relevant to the class they're occurring in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually raising the event.

Remove this line:

```
this._serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceviedHandler;
```

And modify the function:

```
public void OnSerialDataRecevied(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    var bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sp.ReadExisting());
    if(DataReceivedHandler != null)
        DataReceivedHandler(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work - `DataReceivedHandler` is unknown in the `SecurityPanel` class, and anyhow `SecurityDataRecevied` never fires in the first place to execute that code.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I've also discovered I didn't have 'Received' spelled correctly :-)